# Change "polar" property dynamically with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I've a simple chart made with the library Highcharts.
I've reproduced the example in a jsfiddle.

What I want to do is to change the polar property of the chart dynamically (with a click on the button of the example), from true to false and vice versa.

I haven't found anything useful in the API reference to change it dynamically.

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eternasparta/CMs36/2/

The HTML of the fiddle

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
<button id="button">Toggle Polar</button>
```

and this is the code of my jsfiddle:

```
$(function () {
// create the chart
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        //start with polar at true
        polar:true
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});

   //var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
   $('#button').click(function() {
      //toggle polar here
   });
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unforutnately this option is not possible, but you can destroy() and create new chart with the same options.